# Configurable rolling log file name

Tags: node.js, log4js-node

I am using `log4js` to log in my node js application. I have configured logger to create a log file when the file size reaches certain max size. The logger creates a file with same filename and `'.'` and index number is appended to the file name where index number is incremented every time a new file is created.

I use current timestamp when file is created in the filename as: `20150730060112.log` then next files created are as `20150730060112.log.1`, `20150730060112.log.2` `20150730060112.log.3` and so on...

I want a next file to be created with current timestamp. For e.g. if `20150730060112.log` file reaches maxLogSize at lets say on `2015-07-31at 07:04:13` then the filename of new file I want to be as `20150731070413.log`.

Please let me know if this is possible or any work around to get to this.

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: What problem use fie name pattern? https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/wiki/Date-rolling-file-appender

Comment: I tried using Date Rolling file but that doesn't suits my requirement.